# friend function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, friend-function

ListNode.h

```
class ListNode{
public:
    int val;
    ListNode *next;

    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *p) : val(x), next(p) {} 
    ~ListNode() {}

    void print();      
    friend ListNode* vectorToListNode(vector<int>& nums); 
};
```

ListNode.cpp

```
#include "ListNode.h"
ListNode* vectorToListNode(vector<int>& nums)
{
    ListNode* dummy=new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* p=dummy;    
    for (int num:nums) 
    {
        p->next = new ListNode(num);
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next=nullptr;
    p=dummy->next;
    delete dummy;
    return p;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ListNode.h"
int main()
{
    vector<int> nums={1,2,3};
    ListNode* head=vectorToListNode(nums);
    head->print();
    return 0;
}
```

I get a error:'vectorToListNode' was not declared in this scope in VScode. Why, How to fix it when vectorToListNode is still a friend fuction.

Comment: If everything is `public:` you don't need to friend.

Comment: friend ListNode* vectorToListNode(vector<int>& nums); it is in ListNode.h, why it is not declared

Comment: `friend ListNode* vectorToListNode(vector<int>& nums);` doesn't declare a function, you need to declare the function in the header file

Comment: I don't understand. can you write it's right code?

Comment: It means in main.cpp ```#include "ListNode.h"  ListNode* vectorToListNode(vector<int>& nums);```